# Since the transaction is uncommitable, then in the code (in catch block), why are they checking `IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1`

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-using-trycatch-with-xact_state

In this example, SET XACT_ABORT is ON. This makes the transaction uncommittable when the constraint violation error occurs.

Since the transaction is uncommitable, then in the code (in catch block), why are they checking `IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1`. This line will never be reached.

Full code is pasted below:

```
-- Check to see whether this stored procedure exists.  
IF OBJECT_ID (N'usp_GetErrorInfo', N'P') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP PROCEDURE usp_GetErrorInfo;  
GO  
  
-- Create procedure to retrieve error information.  
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetErrorInfo  
AS  
    SELECT   
         ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_LINE () AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
GO  
  
-- SET XACT_ABORT ON will cause the transaction to be uncommittable  
-- when the constraint violation occurs.   
SET XACT_ABORT ON;  
  
BEGIN TRY  
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;  
        -- A FOREIGN KEY constraint exists on this table. This   
        -- statement will generate a constraint violation error.  
        DELETE FROM Production.Product  
            WHERE ProductID = 980;  
  
    -- If the DELETE statement succeeds, commit the transaction.  
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    -- Execute error retrieval routine.  
    EXECUTE usp_GetErrorInfo;  
  
    -- Test XACT_STATE:  
        -- If 1, the transaction is committable.  
        -- If -1, the transaction is uncommittable and should   
        --     be rolled back.  
        -- XACT_STATE = 0 means that there is no transaction and  
        --     a commit or rollback operation would generate an error.  
  
    -- Test whether the transaction is uncommittable.  
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1  
    BEGIN  
        PRINT  
            N'The transaction is in an uncommittable state.' +  
            'Rolling back transaction.'  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
    END;  
  
    -- Test whether the transaction is committable.
    -- You may want to commit a transaction in a catch block if you want to commit changes to statements that ran prior to the error.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1  
    BEGIN  
        PRINT  
            N'The transaction is committable.' +  
            'Committing transaction.'  
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;     
    END;  
END CATCH;  
GO
```

Comment: Indeed, I would never use `XACT_ABORT` and `TRY/CATCH` together as it doesn't usually make sense. The `CATCH` does get executed, but you cannot `COMMIT`

Comment: But in the catch block you can log error and rollback. So why not use xact abort and try/catch together?

Answer (score 2):

The example code CATCH block code is not dependent on the `XACT_ABORT` setting and will behave differently depending on the `XACT_ABORT` at run time. This allows one to observe the differences by toggling `SET XACT_ABORT ON` and `SET XACT_ABORT OFF` in the example script.

Uncommittable applies only with `SET XACT_ABORT ON` and TRY/CATCH is employed. With no TRY/CATCH and `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, the transaction is rolled back immediately and there is no opportunity to COMMIT since no further code executes.  With TRY/CATCH and `SET XACT_ABORT OFF`, the transaction remains committable. Below is a general summary of the behavior.

| XACT_ABORT | TRY/CATCH | Behavior |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ON | YES | transaction uncommittable and CATCH block entered |
| ON | NO | transaction rolled back and no further code executes |
| OFF | YES | transaction remains open and committable and CATCH block entered |
| OFF | NO | transaction remains open and committable and batch continues |

On a side note, I have seen developers unwittingly copy such example code and use it as boiler plate error handling in production code. Rarely does one want to `COMMIT` in a `CATCH` block after an error; one would mostly commonly `ROLLBACK` and rethrow after an error and not bother checking `XACT_STATE()`.

Comment: Does transaction become uncommittable because of TRY block? Had there been no TRY then there would be no XACT STATE?

Comment: @variable, I updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: Thanks. So just to confirm, setting xact abort to ON means that there is no purpose of XACT STATE = 1 in catch block. I wonder why they have given this in the documentation then.

Comment: @variable, correct. I think the reason for `SET XACT_ABORT ON` in the example script is to show the behavior with the recommended ON setting. Since the script includes `XACT_STATE() = 1` too, you can then run the same script with only with only a change to `SET XACT_ABORT OFF` to see the difference.

Comment: In the comment they have mentioned that "You may want to commit a transaction in a catch block if you want to commit changes to statements that ran prior to the error.". So this seems to be the solution where even though there is an error you would like everything prior to the error to be committed.

Comment: @variable, `SET XACT_ABORT OFF` is required if you want to commit after an error. Such a requirement is quite rare in my experience. I don't recall ever doing that in my 25+ years of using SQL Server. The purpose of a database transaction is to guarantee all-or-none.